# ASP.net TextBox TextMode="Date", How do I set value from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set value from code behind in `TextBox` and `TextMode = "Date"`, but browser is not showing anything. I am using Chrome and Bootstrap.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtDateFrom" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">From Date</asp:Label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateFrom1" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom1" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="From Date field is required." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="SetRelase" />
</div>
```

**CodeBehind:**

`txtDateFrom1.Text = "01/01/2010";`

Comment: Can you show your code behind? IF txtDateFrom1.Text = "01/01/2010"; is the only code in Code behind, try to add DataBind();

Comment: txtDateFrom1.Text = "01/01/2010";

Comment: Still the same result if you add Databind(); in the method you add text to the textbox?

Comment: Still not working...                                                                                    txtDateFrom1.Text = "2010/01/01";
                txtDateFrom1.DataBind();

Answer (score 12):

Apperently it is in the [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value) for html5 type `date` that the date should be formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd` so please try:

```
txtDateFrom1.Text = "2010-01-01";
```

Comment: To expand slightly, yes, the approval needs to be in yyyy-MM-dd format and you can assign your date object using .ToString and pass in the format:

txtDate.Text = myDateTimeObject.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")