# Unable to display date in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function called PopulateProviderInformation which populates personal and employee information onto form controls ie textboxes, dropdownlists,etc. Everything populates fine, however, the dates do not. Please see my backend code:

```html
protected void PopulateProviderInformation()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = "spPopulateProviderInformation", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProviderID", Session["CurrentProviderID"].ToString());

                if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { sqlConn.Open(); }

                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    TbEmployeeNumber.Text = read["EmployeeNumber"].ToString();
                    TbSSN.Text = read["SSN"].ToString();
                    DDLContractType.Text = read["ContractType"].ToString();
                    TbFirstname.Text = read["Firstname"].ToString();
                    TbLastname.Text = read["Lastname"].ToString();
                    TbMiddleInitial.Text = read["MiddleInitial"].ToString();
                    TbContractRenewalDate.Text = read["ContractRenewalDate"].ToString();
                    DDLPosition.Text = read["Position"].ToString();
                    DDLSpecialty.Text = read["Specialty"].ToString();
                    DDLPrimaryDepartment.Text = read["PrimaryDepartment"].ToString();
                    DDLSecondaryDepartment.Text = read["SecondaryDepartment"].ToString();
                    DDLGender.Text = read["Gender"].ToString();
                    TbBirthdate.Text = read["Birthdate"].ToString();
                    TbEmailAddress.Text = read["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                    TbPhoneNumber.Text = read["PhoneNumber"].ToString();
                    TbAddress.Text = read["Address"].ToString();
                    TbPassportNumber.Text = read["PassportNumber"].ToString();
                    DDLCitizenship.Text = read["Citizenship"].ToString();
                    DDLVisa.Text = read["Visa"].ToString();

                }

                read.Close();
               
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close(); cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This is my frontend:

```html
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Birthdate</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TbBirthdate" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.net TextBox TextMode="Date", How do I set value from codebehind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515668/asp-net-textbox-textmode-date-how-do-i-set-value-from-codebehind)

Comment: The fields should be populated by values from the database. Everything populates fine except for the dates. Ive tried running breakpoints and noticed that the value for dates were showing date AND time even if ive set it to just DATE.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue by using DateTime.Parse:

```html
TbContractRenewalDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(read["ContractRenewalDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: This is definitely wrong. You should not take a date, then tostring it, then parse it, then tostring it again. At least some of those steps can be removed. What is the type of ContractRenewalDate in the database?

Comment: Thank you for your response. ContractRenewalDate is date type in the database.